# Code should return highest of two numbers entered by the user

Tags: ruby

This is the code.

```
puts "Give me a number"
one = gets.chomp
puts "Give me another number"
two = gets.chomp

if one > two
    puts "This is the bigger number #{one}"
else
    puts "This is the bigger number #{two}"
end
```

I don't know where my fault is.

Comment: Your code also can be DRY-ed: `puts "This is the bigger number #{one > two ? one : two}"`.

Comment: What is your fault?

Comment: I dont see any problem, this code works correctly for me.

Answer (score 2):

you didn't change them to integer, `gets.chomp` gives you string.

```
 puts "Give me a number"
 one = gets.chomp.to_i
 puts "Give me another number"
 two = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are gathering input from an external user of your "application", you then have to decide how you want to manage wrong input and conversion.

- In any case, gets will return a String
- You are going for numbers, but are they `Integer`, `Float` ?

Since `String` is `Comparable`, your original code will run but will probably not yield the expected returns.

Let's say you are only interested in Integers.

You will have three conversion functions to consider :

- `Kernel#Integer` (which is included in the top-level binding)
- `String#to_i`.

`String#to_i` will never return an error.

```
 'abcd'.to_i      #=> 0
 '1.2'.to_i       #=> 1
 nil.to_i         #=> 0
```

`Kernel#Integer` will return an error if the String is not a valid Integer. (which I generally find more appropriate for user inputs).

```
Integer('0')     #=> 0
Integer('abcd')  #=> ArgumentError
Integer(nil)     #=> TypeError
```

Finally, you will have to compare your inputs. I personnally would use `Array#max` since it conveys optimal readability (at the expense of performance still, but you do not seem to be in a performance critical system).

My final code would look like this (without error handling):

```
inputs = []
2.times do
  puts 'Give me a number'
  inputs << Integer(gets.chomp) # or use gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts "This is the bigger number : #{inputs.max}"
```

More refactoring can be done but I don't think it would serve for beginners in Ruby.